# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `object'

Tags: c#, object, arraylist, indexing

**H**ere is my code: An ArrayList of ArrayList that returns a float:

```
public ArrayList walls=new ArrayList(); 

public void Start()
{
    walls[0] = ReturnInArrayList(279,275,0,0,90);
    walls[1] = ReturnInArrayList(62,275,0,0,0);
    walls[2] = ReturnInArrayList(62,275,62,0,90);
    walls[3] = ReturnInArrayList(217,275,62,-62,0);
    walls[4] = ReturnInArrayList(62,275,279,0,90);
    walls[5] = ReturnInArrayList(41,275,279,0,0);
    walls[6] = ReturnInArrayList(279,275,320,0,9);
    walls[7] = ReturnInArrayList(320,275,0,-279,0); 

    for (int i = 0; i < walls.Length; i++) {
        float a = (float)walls[i][0];
        float b = (float)walls[i][1];
        float c = (float)walls[i][2];
        float d = (float)walls[i][3];
        float e = (float)walls[i][4];
    }
}

ArrayList ReturnInArrayList(float a,float b,float c, float d, float e)
{
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    arrayList.Add(a);
    arrayList.Add(b);
    arrayList.Add(c);
    arrayList.Add(d);
    arrayList.Add(e);
    return arrayList;
}
```

It gives me the following error:

> error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   `object'

I already did the casting, what is wrong? :(

Comment: Does the compiler provide a hint as to where the error might be?

Comment: I don't see where your code applies indexing to an expression of type object. Do we get a clue?

Comment: Use classes and add them to a strongly typed `List<YourClass>`.

Comment: Yes, it provides hint, sorry:

All these lines:

"
float a=(float)paredes[i][0];
float b=(float)paredes[i][1];
float c=(float)paredes[i][2];
float d=(float)paredes[i][3];
float e=(float)paredes[i][4];
"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that `paredes[i]` returns an `object` which is the return type of the `ArrayList` indexer. You need to cast this to an `ArrayList` to be able to access it:

```
float a= (float)((ArrayList)paredes[i])[0];
```

A better solution though is to use generics and populate a `List<float>` instead:

```
List<float> RetornaEmList(float a,float b,float c, float d, float e)
{
    return new List<float> { a, b, c, d, e };
}
```

then `paredes` is a `List<List<float>>` and your accessor can be changed to:

```
float a = paredes[i][0];
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I was iterating over the rows in a datatable with foreach (var row in dt.Rows) {} and it wasn't recognizing the typical row["ID"]. Once I changed var to DataRow everything worked.

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayList` stores objects without limiting what type those objects are.  When you access the objects stored in an `ArrayList`, the compiler doesn't know what type they are, so it just gives you type `object`.

You're storing an `ArrayList` of `float` in your outer `ArrayList`.  Since you're always storing floats, it would be better to use a `List<float>` for the inner list, and a `List<List<float>>` for the outer list.  This way you won't have to type cast from `object`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public List<List<float>> paredes = new List<List<float>>();   


Start() {
    paredes[0]=RetornaEmList(279,275,0,0,90);
    paredes[1]=RetornaEmList(62,275,0,0,0);
    paredes[2]=RetornaEmList(62,275,62,0,90);
    paredes[3]=RetornaEmList(217,275,62,-62,0);
    paredes[4]=RetornaEmList(62,275,279,0,90);
    paredes[5]=RetornaEmList(41,275,279,0,0);
    paredes[6]=RetornaEmList(279,275,320,0,9);
    paredes[7]=RetornaEmList(320,275,0,-279,0);    



    for (int i=0;i<paredes.Length;i++)
    {           
        float a=paredes[i][0];
        float b=paredes[i][1];
        float c=paredes[i][2];
        float d=paredes[i][3];
        float e=paredes[i][4];                   
    }
}

List<float> RetornaEmList(float a,float b,float c, float d, float e)
{
    return new List<float> { a, b, c, d, e };
}
```

Since the inner list always has 5 floats, you could also use a `float[]` instead of a `List<float>`

If you just want to make the code work without moving from `ArrayList` to `List`, you need an additional cast:

```
float a = (float)((ArrayList)paredes[i])[0];
```

But it's a lot cleaner just to use `List<float>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you doing the casting?

I would say it must be (did not try with a compiler):

```
for (int i = 0; i < paredes.Length; i++)
{           
    float a=(float)((ArrayList)paredes[i])[0];
    ...                   
}
```

Did you consider using the generic collections instead?

```
public List<List<float>> paredes = new List<List<float>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Code should be like this :

```
//Adding List

paredes.Add(RetornaEmArrayList(279,275,0,0,90));
paredes.Add(RetornaEmArrayList(62,275,0,0,0));
paredes.Add(RetornaEmArrayList(62,275,62,0,90));
paredes.Add(RetornaEmArrayList(217,275,62,-62,0));
paredes.Add(RetornaEmArrayList(62,275,279,0,90));
paredes.Add(RetornaEmArrayList(41,275,279,0,0));
paredes.Add(RetornaEmArrayList(279,275,320,0,9));
paredes.Add(RetornaEmArrayList(320,275,0,-279,0));


//Traversing List

foreach(ArrayList item in paredes)
{
    float a=(float)item[0];
    float b=(float)item[1];
    float c=(float)item[2];
    float d=(float)item[3];
    float e=(float)item[4];
}
```

Comment: I believe that would cause the same error, because `item` is an `object`.

Comment: @svick, item is a list and item[0] is a float element.

Comment: Yeah, but the compiler doesn't know that, which is why the original code caused the error, and your code doesn't fix that.

Comment: As svick points out, this won't compile since `item` will be typed as `object`. It should if you replace `var` with `ArrayList` though.