# Read data from Xcel spreadsheet: Error CS0021

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, excel-interop

Why am I getting this error message?  It is this line in my code that it is complain about:

```
website = x1range.Cells[i][1].value2;
```

I am getting

> Error CS0021 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

This is my code:

```
using System; using System.Threading; using OpenQA.Selenium; using
OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome; using excel =
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Create Editions
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            excel.Application x1app = new excel.Application();
            excel.Workbook x1workbook = x1app.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\DATA\CreateEditions.xlsx");
            excel._Worksheet x1worksheet = (excel._Worksheet)x1workbook.Sheets[1];
            excel.Range x1range = x1worksheet.UsedRange;
            string website;
    
            for(int i=1; i<=3; i++)
            {
               website = x1range.Cells[i][1].value2;
               IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
               driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(website);
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x1range.Cells[i]` returns an `object` which is the return type of the `Range` indexer. So please convert the type of `x1range.Cells[i]` to `Range`.
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004442/cannot-apply-indexing-with-to-an-expression-of-type-object)

```
website = (string)((Range)x1range.Cells[i])[1].value2;
```