# c# get multidimensional array value

Tags: c#, arrays

How to get data from array sample code below

```
var AllData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "TestFun", await TestFun() },
        };
var TestFun = AllData["TestFun"] // ok
ArrayList Humidity = (ArrayList)AllData["TestFun"]; // Error
String String1= TestFun["String1"] // ???

private static async Task<Dictionary<string, object>> TestFun() { 
    var MultiArray = new  Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "String1", "Value1"},
        };
    return MultiArray;
}
```

Error

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type > 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' to type > 'System.Collections.ArrayList'.'

Or

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Tried to get an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004442/cannot-apply-indexing-with-to-an-expression-of-type-object) but couldn't find a solution...

Comment: Did you try `((ArrayList)AllData)["TestFun"]`?

Comment: There are no arrays in this code, much less multidimensional arrays. `AllData` is a dictionary containing the *result* of calling `TestFun()`. That method returns a `Dictionary<string, object>`, not an array.  The error is telling you you tried to cast that `Dictionary<string,object>` to an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Whatever you want to do, this cod is a very convoluted and hard-to-read way to do it.

Comment: That's right, TestFun() returns as you say and puts it in AllData. So the question is that I can get through to the first dictionary (AllData["TestFun"]), but there is no return to from function TestFun(). but debugin ok all show. and the question is how to get through. I'm just learning, sorry for being stupid....

Comment: I just need to create an array object in the  TestFun()  and return it and place it in the AllData. in PHP I would write the following code 
`function TestFun(){
return [
"String1" => "Value1"
]
}
$AllData= [
"TestFun" => TestFun()
];
var_dump($AllData["TestFun"]["String1"]) // Value1

`

Answer (score 2):

`TestFun()` returns a `Dictionary<string,object>`.

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type > 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' to type > 'System.Collections.ArrayList'.'
```

The exception tells you that it is not possible to cast/convert it to an `ArrayList`. You are trying to go from apples to monkeys.

You can either replace the type of the `MultiArray` variable to be an `ArrayList` or change the cast type to `Dictionary<string,object>`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, object> TestFun = (Dictionary<string, object>)AllData[key: "TestFun"];
string String1 = (string) TestFun["String1"];
Console.WriteLine(String1); // Value1
```